# Show that matrix $M$ is not orthogonal if it contains column of all ones.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Original problem:

> We have invertible matrix $M$ dimension $n$ over the $\mathbb F_2$. If $M$ contains column of all ones, then there exists two different rows $V,W$ of $M$ such that: $$<V,W>=\sum_{i}v_iw_i=1. $$

After sometime and with the help of my friend we find out that the problem is equal to the $$M*M^T\neq I,$$ where $I$ is the identical matrix.

And this problem can be solved by solving this one:

> We have invertible matrix $M$ dimension $n$ over the $\mathbb F_2$. If $M$ contains column of all ones, then it is **not** orthogonal matrix.

With $\mathbb F_2$ we denote the field with two elements: zero and one.

Every suggestions and ideas are welcome.

**Edit:** It's all ok when $n$ is even, but the odd $n$'s are problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $V$ is the row of all $1$'s, and $W$ is any other row. Then $V\cdot W = 0$ implies that $W$ must contain an even number of entries which are non-zero. But then $W \cdot W = 0$.

Comment: We can't have row or column with all zeros, the matrix is invertible (nonsingular).

Comment: Just a typo. I meant a row of all 1's.

Comment: This is really short. Took me a while to wrap my head around how to apply this to the problem since it originally talks about a *column* of 1's and I tried to figure out if it's another typo or if you just have to interpret it right. Turns out it's the latter. (Columns of $M$ are rows of $M^T$; look at $M^TM$ and use argument above to see $(M^TM)_{ij}=M_i\cdot M_j\neq I_{ij}$ (where $M_i$ is column $i$) by noting that $M_i\cdot M_j$ should be $\delta_{ij}$ if $M^TM$ actually was $I$.)

Comment: That was also a mistake on my part, but because of exactly what you said we don't have to make the distinction between the situation. Thank you for pointing that out, I should probably be a bit more careful in the future.